# How to create menu and submenu using two tables?

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me how to create vertical menu or sub menu using these tables in PHP.

The two tables are `cat(id,cat_name,main_cat_id)` and `main_cat(id,main_cat_name)`.

### main_category table

```
id  main_category_name
1   Hotels
2   Compressors
3   Apparel & Clothing
4   Automobile
5   Car Rentals
6   Mobiles & Accessories
7   Computers & Peripherals
8   Doctors
9   Education
```

### category table

```
id  category_name   main_category_id
1   Pizza Center    1
2   2 Star Hotel    1
3   Hotel & Restaurant  1
4   5 Star Hotel    1
5   Air Compressor  2
6   Flare Nuts  2
7   Auto Accessories-Car Stereos    4
8   Automotive Parts, Components & Spares   4
9   Motorcycles, Scooters & Two Wheeler Parts   4
```

Comment: What database managing system are you using? You basically need to: 1. get the content from the database, 2. iterate through each result (most likely with a while or foreach loop), 3. output the needed html code according to your menu structure.

Comment: -1 for unreadable formatting. And why two tables? Maybe you should look into Nested Sets.

Comment: but i want to create menu and sub menu. I have two tables in database. cat(id,cat_name,main_cat_id) and main_cat(id,main_cat_name). main_cat is main menu and cat is sub menu

Comment: Thanks for providing your table structure - that is good in questions like this. However, it's not appropriate to add it in a question title. It is much better to add it in the body of the question, like my edit. I've used the formatting tools to make it much more readable as well - give them a go on your next question please.

Comment: What @kenshin23 said seems to be a good approach. Could you give this a go and edit that attempt in? Your database structure and data is a good start, but we like to see a prior attempt relating to the actual topic of the question - so an initial try in PHP would be very useful.

Comment: halfer you know this question's answer. please help me

Comment: halfer I want to crate 
menu and submenu using these tables main_category(id,main_category_name)and  category(id,category_name,main_category_id)

Answer (score 0):

My policy of encouraging a prior attempt applies here. You've laid out the database, which is great, but you need to open a text editor and start on the PHP. You can do it!

Readers here *could* give you a working answer, but that suffers a number of drawbacks:

- Firstly, they might misunderstand what you need, and so spend a long time on something that does not help you.
- Secondly, there are several million people out there that would like people to work for them for free, and we'd be here until Doomsday if we did that.
- Finally, if you get a working answer with no personal research, you might not learn anything.

Here's a suggested plan of action:

- Install WAMP/MAMP/LAMP on your computer
- Set up your database structure and test data in a MySQL instance on your development machine
- Write some PHP code to connect to the database and run a test query on it, dumping the data in a web page
- Once that works, modify the query to read the categories, using an `ORDER` clause to get them in the right order
- Now you have enough information to create a menu. Look up the format of a `<select>` tag using `<option>` tags, each of which contains the name from your database. You'll need a `value` attribute for each one - this is usually the `id` from each row of the database
- Wrap the above in a `<form>`
- From here, you can expand your menu to contain a second level. The simplest way of doing that is to research the `<optgroup>` tag - much under-used, in my opinion. This allows you to set up a two-level menu that is intuitive for users and simple to read values from in code.

Give that a go?